# Perform a command when a specific text occurs in a log file

Tags: tail, systemctl, logfiles, exceptions

Is there any way to achieve something like this?
Whenever some specific word (or combination of them) occurs in log file, I want to perform specific action. For example: whenever there occurs a word "exception" in a logfile, I want to perform "systemctl restart myservice". 
I`m curious, because I might be needing this as a temporary workaround.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to the following example. See `man tail` for the options used:

```
/usr/bin/tail -f --follow=name --retry -n0 $logfile |\
  /bin/grep --line-buffered "exception" \
  | while read -r line ; do
    # do something with $line if you wish
    systemctl restart your_service
done
```